# ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY VARIABLE Accessed By INDEX using BASH in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, variables, associative-array

I'm using Ubuntu terminal installed over Window 10. I create ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY VARIABLE and access in using INDEX using BASH in Ubuntu.

```
### 84) Create an ARRAY VARIABLE Accessed By Value

    declare -A car
    car[BMW]=i8
    car[TOYOTA]=Corolla
    car[Honda]=Civic
    car[Mercedes]=Benz

    echo "${car[TOYOTA]}"
```

It should return 'Corolla'. But instead it returns: 'Benz'

[image: output]

Comment: Use `-A` not `-a`, see `help declare` and [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html)

Comment: Your code works correctly. Please run your code in a fresh terminal.

Answer (score 2):

`declare -a` creates a **numerically indexed** array.
`declare -A` creates an **associative** array.

Numerically indexed arrays place the index part of `var[idx]=value` into an arithmetic context. In an arithmetic context, variables can be used without the "parameter expansion syntax" (i.e. the `$`). Unset variables use the value zero.

So, what you're doing with

```sh
declare -a car # '-a' used to let this variable have assigned values below
car[BMW]=i8
car[TOYOTA]=Corolla
car[Honda]=Civic
car[Mercedes]=Benz
```

is assigning each value to the index zero of the array.

`declare -p` is a handy way to inspect a variable:

```sh
$ declare -p car
declare -a car=([0]="Benz")
```

with `declare -A` instead, we get:

```sh
$ declare -p car
declare -A car=([Honda]="Civic" [TOYOTA]="Corolla" [BMW]="i8" [Mercedes]="Benz" )
```

Comment: Thanks @Glenn Jackman. Though I watched a video with the same code I posted above (except for '-A', which was a typo on my side.) So, the guy in the tutorial it returned 'Corolla'.